# google script if statement didn't work

Tags: google-apps-script

Can anyone help me with my script.

```
function myFunction() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

var December = ss.getSheetByName("12");
var range = December.getRange("A:A");

var emailRange = range.getValues();

var Form1 = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
var emailList = Form1.getRange("K:K").getValues();

for(x in emailRange)
{
  if(x == 0)
    continue
  var email = emailRange[x];
  if(email == "")
    break;

j = 1
for(i in emailList)
{
  var row = emailList[i];

  if(row == "")
  {
    break;
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(email + " - " + row);
  if(row == email)
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("OK");
  }
}
```

the if statement `if(row == email)` is not working. I used debug, and the variables are the same, but it's still not getin.

[image: debug screenshot with two variables have same value]

Comment: Please add more details. A screenshot of the script debugger showing the types and values of the related variables could work or you could write the exact wording. Reference [mcve].

Comment: @RichArt, I tried, and still not working

Comment: Shouldn't === email[1] do it based on the debug snapshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Short answer

Replace if(row == email) by if(row[0] == email[0])

## Explanation

`row` and `email` are of array type. You should compare their elements.